# Finding the limit for $\theta$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

To find out the magnetic field  for infinite  wire, we can have an equation

$$B= \frac{\mu_0 I}{4\pi s}(\sin\theta_2 - \sin\theta_1) $$
[image]

But how the  limit of  theta could be $\theta_1 = -\pi/2$ and $\theta_2 = \pi/2$?

In case of  square wire, for each edge the limit has changed to   $\theta_1 = -\pi/4$ and $\theta_2 = \pi/4$?

How the limit of theta  works here?

Comment: Formula is wrong. Its $4\pi s$ and not $2\pi s$.

Comment: sorry for the typo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Here the angle $\theta_2$ has a positive value where as the value of $\theta_1$ is negative. Now if the length of the current carrying wire $AB$ is increased then the corresponding angles $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ also increased in magnitude. For a infinite wire the angles gets its maximum limiting value $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

So we can say, for infinite wire the value of $\theta_1$ is $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\theta_2$ is $+\frac{\pi}{2}$.It is so, because if we consider a coordinate axis along the $s$ then, $\theta_2$ is in the positive side of the axis whereas $\theta_1$ is in negative side.

Similarly if we going to calculate magnetic induction at the center $(C)$ of the a square wire then the value of $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ must be $-\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $+\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Now in your second figure, the angle $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$, both are in the same side of $s$, i.e. in the same side of the axis. That's why in that case both $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ have same sign.

I think it is clear now...